# Django: do not create migration when adding custom manager to auth.User

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, migration, django-authentication

I would like to add a custom manager to the built-in `auth.User` model.

I avoid switching to my own user model because of existing data in the database linking to the auth_user table.

So I add the following to models.py:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User, UserManager

class ActiveUserManager(UserManager):
    use_in_migrations = False
    def get_queryset(self):
        return super().get_queryset().filter(is_active=True)

# Monkeypatch auth.User to have custom manager
User.add_to_class('active_users', ActiveUserManager())
```

This seems to work, until when I run `python manage.py makemigrations`, Django creates a migration file `000n_auto_20181002_1721.py` in `myvenv/Lib/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/migrations` folder, with the following content:

```
# imports omitted
class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('auth', '0008_alter_user_username_max_length'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.AlterModelManagers(
            name='user',
            managers=[
                ('active_users', django.db.models.manager.Manager()),
                ('objects', django.contrib.auth.models.UserManager()),
            ],
        ),
    ]
```

Setting `use_in_migrations = False` in class `ActiveUserManager` does not help.

I would appreciate your suggestions on how to avoid creating this migration file or how to add a custom manager to the built-in `auth.User` model without this behavior. I am using Django 1.11.

Comment: Did you solve it?

Comment: @Daviddd No. But I cannot reproduce it today...

Comment: thanks for replying. I will dig into it, same issue here https://github.com/divio/django-cms/issues/4317 and also

Comment: @Daviddd thanks for the link. [Their fix](https://github.com/divio/django-cms/commit/fb8caabb9aaa9081a9cd036776518757a05d4c6b?diff=unified) was adding `use_in_migrations = False`. It indeed works if I subclass `auth.User` and use `MyUser` model. The issue arises from `User.add_to_class('active_users', ActiveUserManager())`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Figured it out.

I needed to also add `'objects'` manager to `User` class, otherwise Django treats `'active_users'` as the default manager.

Full code below:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User, UserManager

class ActiveUserManager(UserManager):
    use_in_migrations = False
    def get_queryset(self):
        return super().get_queryset().filter(is_active=True)

# IMPORTANT! to add 'objects' manager
# Otherwise Django treats 'active_users' as the default manager
User.add_to_class('objects', UserManager())

# Monkeypatch auth.User to have custom manager
User.add_to_class('active_users', ActiveUserManager())
```

I realized this by reading [ModelState.fromModel()](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.11/django/db/migrations/state.py#L523), where `'active_users'` was `_default_manager` when `'objects'` manager was not set by `User.add_to_class('objects', UserManager())`.

Default manager gets added to migration even when `use_in_migrations = False` is set.

Comment: Thanks for this. Unfortunately in my case doesn' t work: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55923797/django-2-2-abstractuser-and-migration-issue. It still creates n migration files.