# Django 2.2 AbstractUser and migration issue

Tags: django, django-models

I extend the Django user model like this:

```
#core.models

class Institute(models.Model):
    phone_regex = RegexValidator(regex=r'^\+?1?\d{9,15}$', message=institute_phone_help_text)

    name = models.CharField(_('name'), max_length=255)
    description = models.TextField(_('description'), blank=True)
    abbreviation = models.CharField(_('abbreviation'), blank=True, max_length=100)
    address = models.TextField(_('address'), blank=True)
    phone = models.CharField(validators=[phone_regex], max_length=17, blank=True)  # validators should be a list
    websites = ArrayField(models.URLField(max_length=255), verbose_name=_('websites'), blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _('institute')
        verbose_name_plural = _('institutes')

    def __str__(self):
        return '{0} ({1})'.format(self.name, self.abbreviation)


class User(AbstractUser):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    institute = models.ForeignKey(Institute, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    params = JSONField(_('params'), null=True, blank=True,)
    about_me = models.TextField(_('about me'), blank=True,)
```

With an empty DB each time that I launch `./manage.py makemigrations core` it creates always a new migration file

```
import django.contrib.auth.models
from django.db import migrations


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('core', '0002_auto_20190430_1655'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.AlterModelManagers(
            name='user',
            managers=[
                ('objects', django.contrib.auth.models.UserManager()),
            ],
        ),
    ]
```

I tried different combinations:

```
./manage.py makemigrations core
./manage.py migrate core
./manage.py migrate 

./manage.py makemigrations core
./manage.py makemigrations core

./manage.py makemigrations
./manage.py migrate
```

It always creates the migration file.

Thanks.

D

Comment: Is it create multiple migrations files?

Comment: @shafik yes it does each time I run it.

Comment: When you run makemigrations Do you see this `No changes detected
`

Comment: why is this an issue? is it then creating the same migration again or what?

Comment: if you can, i would start from scratch again (including creating the first migrations).

Comment: I run the makemigrations and it continues to create the same migration: 02, 03, 04 and so on. I started from scratch with the only the 2 models in the question.

Comment: I cannot reproduce what you've seen. I tested with a fresh virtualenv with only Django 2.2 installed. I would suggest starting with a fresh environment also.

Answer (score 1):

if you use `AbstractUser` model make sure you run `makemigrations` before `migrate`.

i had same issue with `AbstractUser`,
I solved it by deleting the sqlite3 file also all migrations files.
After that i run this two commands :

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```

inside your terminal

Let me know if that help!